# Closed form for the sole positive root of the polynomial ${x^\alpha } + {x^{\alpha - 1}} + \cdots + {x^3} + {x^2} -p$, $p > 0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

For a study I'm making about the minimum and maximum radial values of bounded orbits in a central force system with general power law forces, I came across this *special* polynomial equation:

> $${x^\alpha } + {x^{\alpha  - 1}} +  \ldots  + {x^3} + {x^2} -p= 0, \qquad p>0 ,$$

that is

$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\alpha  - 2} {{x^{\alpha  - k}}}  -p=0 .$

The polynomial equation is *special* since:

- all the coefficient of the terms with degree $ \ge 2$ are equal
- the coefficient of the term with degree $1$ is $0$
- the coefficient of the term with degree $0$ is $-p$ with $p>0$

Using *Descartes’ rules of sign* to count the number of real positive zeros of above equation (and seeing the numerical solutions given by Mathematica for positive values of $p$) I know that above equation has a single real positive solution.

I'm also aware that there aren't, in general, closed algebraic forms for the solutions of polynomial equations with degree $ \ge 5$ but I wonder if, given the special form of the equation, it is possible to express the single real positive root in closed form.

Clearly the algebraic expression for the real positive root would depend on $p$ and $\alpha$.

Even if there's no closed form for the real positive root maybe there are tools for exploring above *special* equation (I'm no expert in this field) that I don't know of.

Any link/suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need all that work to see that there is a single positive root - it is clearly increasing on the positive reals and negative at $x=0$, so it has one positive real root.

Comment: Although there is no closed formula for $\alpha \gt 4$, the usual numerical root finding algorithms will have no difficulty giving as much accuracy for the unique positive root as you wish.

Comment: *Degree* is a much more common term for what in the question is called a *grade*.

Comment: Ok made correction grade->degree

Comment: You are solving, $$\frac{x^n-1}{x-1} = x+p+1$$ or equivalently, $$(x^n-1)-(x-1)(x+p+1) = x^n-x^2-px+p = 0\tag1$$ Since you didn't specify what kind of closed-form you want, I think a quadrinomial like $(1)$ can be solved in terms of the _hypergeometric function_, though I am not sure. For comparison on the trinomial, see eq.42 of [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII good hint. That's exactly where I came from before factoring out the solution x=1. Anyway your eq (1) doesn't exactly match the trinomial of eq 42 (${x^w} + {x^q} + c$) in the article you cited so that I don't know if getting some more knowledge about hypergeometric functions can really help me in this specific scope.

Comment: I like to add to my comment. Hypergeometric functions might suffice for *trinomials* like eq.42 in the link. However, for _quadrinomials_,  it might be better to use generalized theta functions as described in [Umemura's paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-8176-4578-6_18). Too bad Eumemura didn't explicitly give the closed-form solution for the special case when there are just four terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no algebraic formula for such a root: In the case $\alpha = 5$, $p = 1$, for example, the Galois group of the resulting polynomial, $$x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - 1 ,$$ is the full symmetric group $S_5$. Since this group is not solvable, there is no expression for any of its roots in terms of basic operations and root extraction.

Of course, in some special cases one may still be able to find a formula; for example, when $p = \alpha - 1$, the unique positive solution is $x = 1$.

Comment: That's what I suspected. Much useful answer. Could you give an example of a 5th degree polynomial that would be solvable?

Comment: E.g. $x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2-4=0$ having a root $x=1$, and so it reduces to a fourth degree polynomial, so it has 5 closed-form roots

Comment: Sure, and one can use the special case I mention to generate such an example: $q(x) = x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - 4$ has root $1$, so it factors as $(x - 1) r(x)$ for some quartic $r$. Thus, the the Galois group of $q$ is isomorphic to the Galois group of $r$, and so is contained in $S_4$, which is solvable, and in particular there is an explicit algebraic formula for its roots. (In fact, $\operatorname{Gal}(q)$ turns out to be $D_8$.)

Comment: @LucaM The following 5th degree polynomial has easily found solutions:  $$0=x^5-1$$